# Angular2 - Unexpected value 'AdDFPComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, components

Looking for help because I could not find the solution to my problem anywhere... When I'm running `ionic run android --prod` or whatever using ngc I get this error:

```
[10:36:15]  ngc started ... 
[10:36:19]  build prod failed: Unexpected value 'AdDFPComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule' 
[10:36:19]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[10:36:19]  Error: Unexpected value 'AdDFPComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

If I don't build in production mode I'm not getting any error...

AdDFPComponent is a Component I wrote and published to NPM, It's working fine when I'm only using the AdDFPComponent.ts in my App, but I want it to work properly using npm install

Here is my AppModule.ts:

```
import { AdDFPComponent } from 'ng2-ad-dfp/bundle/ad-dfp';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    AdDFPComponent,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is my AdDFPComponent.ts:

```
import { things } from '@angular/core';

declare var var1: any;
declare var var2: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'ad-dfp',
  template: `
      <div class="adContainer">
          <div class={{type}}>

          </div>
      </div>
  `,
  style: [`.adContainer { text-align: center; }`]
})
export class AdDFPComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() type: string;

  public settings: any;

  constructor(
    private things: SomeType) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    /* A few functions */
  }
  someFunction() { ... }
}
```

If someone can help me out that would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: Import the module containing `AdDFPComponent` instead of importing component.

Comment: I tried `import { AdDFPComponent } from 'ng2-ad-dfp` but it's still not working...

Comment: Have you exported your component in index.ts file of ng2-ad-dfp?

Comment: Currently have `export * from './bundle/ad-dfp';`
I'll try to import then export directly the component

Comment: Same error with `export { AdDFPComponent } from './bundle/ad-dfp'` in index.d.ts